# firebase cloud messaging not showing any data in reports

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using fcm for push notifcation from past 5-6 days and  the devices are receiving  the push notifcations , but the reports in firebase console is not showing any data.

I am using sendToDevice() method of firebase messaging and the payload looks like this

```
"payload": {
    "data": {
        "appRedirectionURL": "/dashboard",
        "url":"/dashboard",
        "title": "Test 1",
        "body": "hello",
        "pushMessage":"test",
        "inAppNotificationTitle":"testing ",
        "inAppNotifactionBody":"hello"
    }
},
```

attaching the reports tab screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add analytics labels to messages. I haven't found why automatic reports don't work without it. But when I added analytics_label to my messages they started showing up in firebase console

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#adding-analytics-labels-to-messages

Comment: i have added analytics label and still it is  not showing , my message object is 
{
  tokens: [
    '123456abc',      
    '123456abc'       
  ],
  data: {
    title: 'this is a title 7',
    body: 'this is a body 7 ',
    screen: 'random screen',
    notificationType: 'permanentt'
  },
  apns: { payload: { aps: [Object] } },
  fcm_options: { analyticsLabel: 'all_label' }
}